# Writing a loop or function (simple) MATLAB

Tags: matlab, loops

I am a beginner user of Matlab, could you please just help me how to write it as a code.
My inputs are:

port_returns - 196x1 column vector

VaR - a scalar

variance_portfolio - a scalar

```
   port_returns=returns*weights';
    VaR=1.65*sqrt(variance_portfolio);
```

And I want to write a code, which would take **port_returns values, that are less than VaR** **value and average it.**

Could somebody help me with that?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Your pseudocode doesn't make sense. Please revise your code and question to make it clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

`sum(port_returns(port_returns<VaR))/length(port_returns(port_returns<VaR))`

where

`sum(port_returns(port_returns<VaR))`

finds all elements in port_returns smaller than VaR and sums them up,

and is then divided by the number of elements that are smaller than VaR:

`port_returns(port_returns<VaR)`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `port_returns` is an array (vector), you could get the values less than `VaR` by using the following: `less_than_VaR = find(port_returns < VaR);` and then to average them it's very simple using `avg = mean(less_than_VaR);`

reference:

1. [Find Array Elements That Meet a Condition](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/find-array-elements-that-meet-a-condition.html)
2. [Average or mean value of array](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mean.html)

Comment: I tried it by myself as well, however it returned me the indices of the values , not the values itself... However, I have a solution now, thank you for your time and comment.

Comment: Yes I edited the answer since I forgot to use `find`. Anyhow it's worth knowing those functions, and you're welcome.